# Must an inverse of an inner product preserving operator be inner product preserving in an infinite dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products

According to my reasoning it must, because of the following argument:

Let $f:V\to V$ be an invertible inner product preserving linear operator, and let $g=f^{-1}$. Hence,
$$ <g(u)|g(w)>\ =\ <f(g(u))|f(g(w))>\ =\ <u|w> $$
for any $u,w\in V$.

For some reason, in any source I found, the claim in the title was preceded by the assumption that $V$ is finite dimensional, so I wanted to make sure that there isn't any flaw in the very simple argument above.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: FYI - `\langle, \mid, \rangle` produce a nicer looking inner product than < | >: $$\langle u\mid w \rangle$$